# Reverse q-scroll-area

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I would like to reverse the q-scroll-area. With that I mean that I want it to behave like a chat. I want the components to render from the bottom and up, and not from the top. I would also like the on-mount default scroll to be on the bottom and not top.

Is there a simple way to do this or do I have to do it all manually? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quasar framework q-scroll-area is not usually used for chat like modules, they have [Infinite Scroll](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/infinite-scroll) which is a perfect solution issue you are facing. it also support [Reverse Scroll](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/infinite-scroll#Example--Reverse-(Messenger-style)), you can use it by passing a `reverse` prop

```
<template>
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <q-infinite-scroll @load="onLoad" reverse>
      <template slot="loading">
        <div class="row justify-center q-my-md">
          <q-spinner color="primary" name="dots" size="40px" />
        </div>
      </template>

      <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" class="caption q-py-sm">
        <q-badge class="shadow-1">
          {{ items.length - index }}
        </q-badge>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum repellendus sit voluptate voluptas eveniet porro. Rerum blanditiis perferendis totam, ea at omnis vel numquam exercitationem aut, natus minima, porro labore.
      </div>
    </q-infinite-scroll>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Ahh nice, that looks better! However, I'm not able to get the reverse to work. It still defaults scroll to the top of the list. I have done the exact thing as above except for the @load part.

Comment: ok you should try following the docs of the link i shared

Comment: I did. The reverse literally does nothing :/

Comment: why not its working properly here

https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101=https%3A%2F%2Fquasar.dev%2Fvue-components%2Finfinite-scroll

Comment: I finally found out why. The reason it works in the example is because reverse defaults scroll to bottom on mounted, while I ask for data through database. On mounted I don't have the data to be sent to the bottom.